# Can someone tell me books or papers on subalgebras of $\operatorname{SL}(3)$?

Tags: matrices, reference-request, lie-algebras

I hope to find the smallest subalgebra of $\operatorname{SL}(3)$ that contain the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a & 0\\0 & 0 & b\\c & d & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ Are there any references where I can find this information?

Answer (score 2):

- [*The Structure of Linear Groups*](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_structure_of_linear_groups.html?id=Nv3uAAAAMAAJ) by John Dixon
- [*Linear Algebra and Group Theory*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Linear_Algebra_and_Group_Theory.html?id=37MatX78PgYC) by Vladimir Smirnov
- [*Linear Representations of Finite Groups*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Linear_Representations_of_Finite_Groups.html?id=NCfZgr54TJ4C) by Jean-Pierre Serre